# How is this Python 2.7 setdefault/ defaultdict code giving a nested result?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, nested, defaultdict

This seems to be a pretty straightforward use of `setdefault` and `defaultdict` which I am not able to understand, it would be great if someone could explain "why" the code below works.

```
d = {}

for name in ['foo', 'bar', 'bars']:
    t = d
    for char in name:
        t = t.setdefault(char,{}) # Should be a empty {}

print d
# Prints {'b': {'a': {'r': {'s': {}}}}, 'f': {'o': {'o': {}}}}
```

I am not able to understand how this piece of code works. When the line `t = t.setdefault(char,{})` executes it should assign a empty dictionary to t, but how is it affecting d such that d ends up becoming a nested dictionary?

Also, what would be the equivalent of the above if I were to use `defaultdict`. I came up with this which is wrong:

```
d1 = defaultdict(dict)

for name in ['foo', 'bar', 'bars']:
    t1 = d1
    for char in name:
        t1 = t1[char]

print d1
```

It would be great if someone could point out as to how one should understand defaultdicts

Comment: As with lists, `t` and `d` both point to the same dict object. When `t` changes, `d` changes as well.

Comment: Ok, I kind of get the idea now. So when the statement t = t.setdefault(char,{}) executes, the part **t.setdefault(char,{})** mutates the dictionary d, and since the right hand side evaluvates to {}, t is set to {}. Would that understanding be correct?

Comment: @VikashRajaSamuelSelvin:  Your understanding is correct.  The program would work the same, and be clearer if it didn't use the `t` variable at all, and just did a `_ = d.setdefault(char, {})`.  The underscore variable would give a clue that this assignment was just being thrown away (which is is) then.

Comment: @Gerrat If I use _ = d.setdefault(char, {}) it returns **{'a': {}, 'b': {}, 'f': {}, 'o': {}, 's': {}, 'r': {}}** which is what I expected but the statement **t = t.setdefault(char,{})** it effectively creates a trie of the form **{'b': {'a': {'r': {'s': {}}}}, 'f': {'o': {'o': {}}}}**. I can't seem to wrap my head around that, if you could explain why that behaviour occurs it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @VikashRajaSamuelSelvin:  Ah, I see.  My understanding was incorrect earlier.  It's actually pretty interesting.  I'll see if I can come up with a simple explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll walk through the loop one step at a time, and explain how it proceeds to assign the nested dicts:

```
name = 'foo'
    t = d  # both t and d point to the same empty dict object
    char = 'f'
        t = t.setdefault(char,{})  
        # the first thing evaluated is the right hand side:
        # now d['f'] = {}, since that key wasn't in the dict
        # t points to the same object here
        # now the result of the left side (a new empty dict) is assigned to `t`.
        # this empty dict is also the exact *same* object referenced by d['f'] as well though!
        # so at this point d['f'] = {}, and t = {}, and both those dicts are the same!
    char = 'o'
        t = t.setdefault(char,{})  
        # eval the right side again, so now t['o'] = {}, but remember d['f'] == t
        # so really d['f'] = {'o':{}}
        # and again we assign the result of the right side to a brand new `t`
        # so now d['f']['o'] = {}, and t['o'] = {}, and these empty dicts are 
        # again referencing the same object
    char = 'o'
        t = t.setdefault(char,{})  
        # our `t` from last time is empty, so it gets assigned the same as before
        # and now d['f']['o']['o'] = {}
name = 'bar'
    t = d  # re-start this, but with d['f']['o']['o'] = {}
    char = 'b'
    #...everything proceeds as before - since 'b' is not in `d`, 
    # we start generating nested dicts again
    # ...
...
name = 'bars'
    # main difference here is that d['b']['a']['r'] exists, 
    # so we end up just adding the 's':{} to the end
```

As for the `defaultdict` equivalent, that is a little trickier.
The issue is you need defaultdict's all-the-way-down

I found a way to do that with a little function [here](https://quanttype.net/posts/2016-03-29-defaultdicts-all-the-way-down.html)

```
from collections import defaultdict

def fix(f):
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: f(fix(f), *args, **kwargs)

d1 = fix(defaultdict)()

for name in ['foo', 'bar', 'bars']:
    t1 = d1
    for char in name:
        t1 = t1[char]

print d1
```

Comment: Good explanation ! I can't say more. Thanks.

Comment: That is great! Thank you for the detailed walk through. I am marking this as the answer.

Comment: @VikashRajaSamuelSelvin:.  Thanks.  I answered the 2nd part of your question as well.  It's a little trickier, but works the same.

Comment: @Gerrat Thank you, I was just about to post about the second part. A simple d1 = defaultdict(defaultdict) doesn't work, I am guessing based on your answer that it has something to do with how Python unpacks arguements. What I noticed was that on the 2nd call, t1 changes from type defaultdict<defaultdict> to defaultdict<None>. Thanks for clearing this up too, couldn't upvote due to my reputation though.

Comment: @VikashRajaSamuelSelvin:  It doesn't have to do with how it unpacks - but you were on the right track with defaultdict(defaultdict)...issue is it needs to be more like defaultdict(defaultdict(defaultdict(... all-the-way-down!

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, the line `t = d` does not make a copy of `d`. It only creates a new reference to `d` and stores it in `t`. `t` and `d` now refer to the same object; in other words, you have only one object, but two names for that object. Since that object is a mutable object (a dict, in this case), changing `t` also changes `d` since there is only one object. While that's necessary here, if for some reason in other code you want to make a copy of a mutable object and operate on the copy without modifying the original, you need to `import copy` and use `copy.deepcopy()`.

On the second, the `defaultdict()` constructor expects, as its first argument, a callable that accepts no arguments and returns the default value. However, for this case, that return value would need to be another defaultdict with a callable returning another defaultdict with a callable returning yet another... etc. It's infinite recursion.

So there is no defaultdict equivalent to this code. Instead, the original version with `setdefault` and plain dicts is probably the best and most Pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

how setdefault works in dictionary

```
# case 1
d = {}
temp = d.setdefault("A")
print "d = ", d
print "temp = ", temp
print "id of d = ", id(d), "id of temp = ", id(temp)
# output
d = {'A': None}
temp = None
id of d = 140584110017624, id of temp = 9545840 # memory locations of d, temp

# case 2
d = {}
temp = d.setdefault("A", "default Value")
print "d = ", d
print "temp = ", temp
print "id of d = ", id(d), "id of temp = ", id(temp)
# output
d = {'A': "default Value"}
temp = "default Value"
id of d = 140584110017624, id of temp = 9545840 # memory locations of d, temp
```

I your code `t=d` means memory location of t and d both are same.
so, when the code `t = t.setdefault(char,{})` excecutes first `t.setdefault(char,{})` executes and changes the content in memory location of `t`, then it returns the content then it assigns the new memory location to name `t` and assigns the returned value to it.
memory location of `t` and `d` are same that's the reason `d` is getting affected.